# Random image core- Background shows up when button tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to generate random images when I tap a button, but when I tap the button, both images disappear and only the background shows up.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func PickerTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    //randomize a number for the first image

    var firstrandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(7) + 1

    //construct a string with a random number

    var firstLeftHandImageString: String = String(format: "rud%i", firstrandomNumber)

    // set the left hand image view to the asset corresponding to the randomized number

    self.LeftHandImageView.image = UIImage(named: "firstLeftHandImageString")

    //randomize a number for the second image

    var secondrandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(7) + 1

    //construct a string with a random number 

    var secondRightHandImageString: String = String(format: "rud%i", secondrandomNumber)

    //set the right hand image view to the asset corresponding to the randomized number

    self.RightHandImageView.image = UIImage(named: "secondRightHandImageString")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.RightHandImageView.image = UIImage(named: "secondRightHandImageString")
```

creates an image from the asset named "secondRightHandImageString"

if you want an image created with the string that you generated, you would need (note the lack of double quotes around the variable name)

```
self.RightHandImageView.image = UIImage(named: secondRightHandImageString)
```

Comment: thank you so so much!! wow, i really need to build my de-bugging skills.. i stared at that forever and compared it to the tutorial.. and never saw that. Removing them worked like a charm!!